# How do I re-direct FilePrint's output?

Tags: streams, printing

I recently wanted to use [`FilePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FilePrint.html) to print the contents somewhere else but in the notebook I was using. However, the obvious-seeming solution doesn't work at all:

```
In[137]:= temp = With[{str = OpenWrite[]},
             Block[{$Output = str},
              Print["fee fi fo fum"]];
             Close[str]];

In[138]:= FilePrint[temp]
          "fee fi fo fum"

In[139]:= With[{str=OpenWrite[]},
           Block[{$Output = str},
            FilePrint[temp]];
           Close[str]];
          "fee fi fo fum"
```

Since the obvious solution doesn't work, does anybody know a less obvious solution, preferably one that doesn't involve re-implementing `FilePrint` myself? Sure, that would be easy, but I'd prefer not to do it.

Comment: I didn't find an easy solution ... but why don't you just use CopyFile[] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only give a partial answer. Your problem arises because `FilePrint` doesn't use `$Output` (stdout). It uses the stderr stream, so you can't capture what it writes by using `Block` and assigning to `$Output`. Unfortunately, I don't think any system variable is bound to stderr. Perhaps I'm wrong. In that case, I hope a more knowable person will be able to complete this answer.

In case anyone is interested, here is how I discovered that `FilePrint` was using stderr.

```
text = "fee fi fo fum";
output = With[{str = OpenWrite[]},
  Block[{$Output = str},
    Print[text]];
  Close[str]];
FilePrint[Print[Streams[]]; output]

{OutputStream[stdout,1],OutputStream[stderr,2]}

"fee fi fo fum"
```

Comment: You shouldn't use LaTeX to do code formatting; LaTeX is there for formulas. Code formatting is done by simply indenting the code by four spaces. To code-format small snippets embedded in the text (like `FilePrint` or `$Output`), enclose the snippet in backquotes.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks for the formatting tips. I've edited the post using your advice.