# Directing output of PrintTemporary to an additional OutputStream

Tags: streams

I want to log messages that I send to the screen, even temporary ones.

By setting `$Output` appropriately, it is possible to log `Print` messages, but not `PrintTemporary` messages:

```
oldout = $Output;
    logfile = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "example.log"}];
    log = OpenWrite[logfile];
    $Output = Append[oldout, log];
Print["Log message printed on screen."];
PrintTemporary["Log message printed temporarily on screen."]; Pause[1];
$Output = oldout;
Close[log];
Print["Contents of file:"];
FilePrint[logfile];
```

gives

> Log message printed on screen.
>
> (Log message printed temporarily on screen.)
>
> Contents of file:
>
> "Log message printed on screen."

Perhaps this is not surprising, but if you start Mathematica in non-gui mode (i.e., "MathKernel" on MacOsX), the `PrintTemporary` output stays permanently on the screen.

How can one direct the output of `PrintTemporary` permanently to an additional output stream?

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3762/how-do-i-re-direct-fileprints-output

Comment: @belisarius The two questions may indeed have similar answers, although the workaround you commented there does not apply here.

Comment: Yes. That's why I haven't voted to close. My comment was for OP, as that question has been idle for a long time :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `PrintTemporary` does not use output streams, but rather is akin to `CellPrint`, I believe you will need to add this functionality manually.  For example:

```
Unprotect[PrintTemporary];

$log = OpenAppend["logfile.txt"];

PrintTemporary[expr_] /; ! TrueQ[ptLog] :=
 Block[{ptLog = True},
  WriteString[$log, expr];
  PrintTemporary @ expr
 ]

Protect[PrintTemporary];
```

Comment: I would consider adding functionality where it would detect if `$log` had anything assigned to it, and revert to the default behavior. +1

Comment: @rcollyer it's merely an example; feel free to edit it or post a more complete answer.